# IndexSizeError while trying to change audio volume

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I am trying to change the volume of the audio and when trying i receive `IndexSizeError: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount` in console log.

Any ideas how to solve this?

My code (HTML):

```
<audio id="localmusic" style="display:none" controls preload="none"> <source src=""> </audio>
```

My code (JS):

`LocalPlay = $("#localmusic");
 LocalPlay.prop("volume", 50);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the volume in range [0, 1]. 50 is out of range.

- **1.0** is highest volume (100%. This is default)
- **0.5** is half volume (50%)
- **0.0** is silent (same as mute)

Comment: Oh! So if i want the volume to go up by 1 id add 1? And if i want to minus 1 i go 0?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by up/down by 1. Simply when you have set volume as e.g. 20% of maximum and you want to make it a little bit louder you set `LocalPlay.prop("volume", 0.21);`

Comment: Oh! I thought it was 0-100 like normal like 0.0 - 1.0. Makes perfect sense and works a charm! Thank you.